# Getting all the column values for a particular row in Hbase

Tags: java, hbase

I wanted to get all the columns under the different columnfamily in hbase for a particular row and the below is the code that i tried to implement using getFamilyMap. It produces a navigablemap with byte[] as key and value.But when i try to do entries.getValue(), i donot get any data.

```
    Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
Get getVal = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(input));
// Reading the data
Result result = table.get(getVal);
NavigableMap<byte[], byte[]>  byteMap = result.getFamilyMap(cfName.getBytes());
for(Map.Entry<byte[],byte[]> entries: byteMap.entrySet()){
    byte[] temp = entries.getKey();
    byte[] value = entries.getValue();
    logger.debug("key:: "+Bytes.toString(temp));
    logger.debug("Value:: "+Bytes.toString(byteMap.get(value)));
}
```

But the below code if i provide, i do get the key and the value. Please let me know whats the difference between these two code and how does the value of the map is affected?

```
for(byte[] map : byteMap.keySet()){
    logger.debug("key:: "+Bytes.toString(map));
    logger.debug("Value:: "+Bytes.toString(byteMap.get(map)));      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at these lines of the failing example:

```
byte[] value = entries.getValue();
logger.debug("Value:: "+Bytes.toString(byteMap.get(value)));
```

You've already got the value as `byte[]`, so you don't need to retrieve anything from the `byteMap`. And indeed, you won't have a key in `byteMap` that corresponds to that value. All you need to log is:

```
logger.debug("Value:: "+Bytes.toString(value));
```